# ArrayList Collection API

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

I have an **ArrayList** (`listOfNumbers`) which contains a number. I have written a Predicate (guava) which gives me a list of **EVEN** numbers (`evenNumberList`) from `listOfNumbers`. I now want all the **ODD** numbers copied to a new **ArrayList**. Wondering if there is a quick way of doing this?

Comment: It is good if you can show some code.

Comment: What do you want to do? A loop could be pretty effecient

Comment: It would be more efficient to loop over the list once and populate the two lists (even & odd) there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your class, have two instance variables: `ArrayList<Integer> oddNumbers` and `ArrayList<Integer> evenNumbers`. Then, your method should look like the following:

```
public void setEvenOdd(ArrayList<Integer> listOfNumbers) {
    ArrayList<Integer> even = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(Integer i : listOfNumbers) {
        if(i % 2 == 0) even.add(listOfNumbers.remove(i));
    }
    this.evenNumbers = even;
    this.oddNumbers = listOfNumbers; // since we removed all even numbers
}
```

Is this what you were asking for?